# Ubuntu Server randomly crashes and hangs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel-graphics, asus, intel

System randomly crashing, cannot find reason

I am running a Jellyfin media server on a machine at home and it has been crashing randomly since it was installed. The system would just crash and hang without kernel panic screens or anything in the system logs. Instead the screen would just go black and the system needs to be forcefully restarted manually. Every time it crashed it happened when the system was idle and doing nothing.

Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 Server (this was installed before 22.04 on kernel 6.2 came out)

System specs:

- Intel Core i5-9400F
- ASUS B360-F Motherboard
- 8GBx1 DDR4 RAM
- Intel ARC A750 Graphics card
- WD Green 120GB SSD for OS
- WD Green 120GB SSD for Jellyfin temp files
- FSP Hexa 85+ 350w power supply (replaced for troubleshooting)
- Seasonic Focus GX 850 (put in for troubleshooting)
- Media is mounted via SMB

Troubleshooting steps performed so far:

- Enable Kdump (didn't dump anything)
- Memtest (No errors)
- FSCK on boot drive (No errors)
- Replace CPU, MB and RAM (Same result)
- Replace Power Supply (Same result)
- Full CPU + GPU stress test (Didn't crash)

Comment: Well, one possible cause is hardware getting into a state where it considers it necessary to simply turn off (if there are such protective functions). I'd say this is caused by ESD-related  damage; did you take precautions for that when building the system?